# CRM 2011 - Plug-In - Operation Timed-Out error while trying to do a HTTP Post in a Plug-in

Tags: plugins, http-post, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I'm having problems when I try to do a HTTP Post in my Plugin (in PostUpdate). I'm getting the "The Operation Has Timed Out"-Error...

Here below you have the C#-code :

```
                        //PUBLISH TO ROBAROV
                        WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(newUri);
                        webRequest.Timeout = 2000;
                        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                        webRequest.Method = "POST";
                        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(parameters);
                        Stream os = null;
                        try
                        {
                            webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
                            os = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
                            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                        }
                        catch (WebException ex)
                        {
                            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            if (os != null)
                            {
                                os.Close();
                            }
                        }                                

                        //ERROR HAPPENS HERE

                        string responseText = "";
                        try
                        { // get the response
                            WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
                            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
                            responseText = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
                        }
                        catch (WebException ex)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Error with response : " + ex.Message);
                        }
```

The error happens when I'm trying to get the response => webRequest.GetResponse();!

I've tried the code out in a simple "Class"-library and there it works like a charm! Is there something I'm doing wrong? The HTTP Post is to a webpage that's not in the same domain....

UPDATE :
Same happens when I do the following with a webclient... And it works in a normal "Console"-application :

```
    private string HttpPostTest(string URL)
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection formData = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
        formData["state"] = "yes";
        byte[] responseBytes = webClient.UploadValues(URL, "POST", formData);
        string Result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
        return Result;
    }
```

I'm getting the following error in the "Event Viewer" :

```
Inner Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Crm.Setup.DiffBuilder, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it can't find a CRM assembly: Microsoft.Crm.Setup.DiffBuilder.dll, is this something which you explicitly call methods from? If so I'd check if the assembly is registered with the plug-in (some instructions below). If not then there are some errors associated with this library from roll up 6, which roll up are you using? You may consider roll up 7 if you are not using that.

Is your plug-in registered in the database or on disk?

If registered on disk then you will need your external assembly in the /server/bin/assembly directory under the CRM installation folder.

If it is registered in the database and you are including a custom external assembly (the error suggests that an assembly cannot be loaded, so this sounds possible), then you will have to ILMerge your assemblies before registering them in the database. This would explain why it works for your local console application and not when run as a plug-in.

If this is the case then you can follow a script like below to ILMerge and register your 'combined' assembly:-

http://www.2wconsulting.com/2010/11/using-ilmerge-with-crm-plugin-assemblies/